# Как получить значение переменной из другого php файла?

Tags: php, сессия, include

Здравствуйте.

Есть 2 файла php: **prioritet.php** и **scoring.php**.

В **priorotet.php** после определенной выборки получаем переменную **$a=результат выборки**.

Вопрос: как в **scoring.php** подключиться к **prioritet.php** и получить только **$a=результат**?

Через include не получилось, т.к. он выводит весь процесс файла.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ, может кому понадобиться: решение-*сессия*.

В **prioritet.php**:
session_start();
$_SESSION['b']=$a;

Далее, в **scoring.php**:
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['b'];

Comment: Сессия это не лучшее место для хранения общих данных,  лучше присвоить значения массиву  http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.globals.php, хотя я думаю что и это вам не нужно

Comment: Можно, как вариант. Но, для моей ситуации, лучше подошло сессия.